# Зависит ли быстродействие базы данных от ее обьема?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Всем доброго времени и суток. Надеюсь на Ваши разъяснения)

Есть программа, которая построчно считывает переданные ей файлы excel и сопоставляет информацию из них по разным параметрам. Файлы могут быть как небольшими, так и по несколько миллионов строк.. Чтобы не напрягать ОЗУ программа создаёт временную базу данных в которую вливается вся информация в три таблицы и обновляется (UPDATE table) когда нужно.

С небольшими объемами программа справляется быстро, но когда передать ей 5-10 файлов по 1-2млн строк, время выполнения анализа сильно и непропорционально увеличивается.

Отсюда есть вопросы:

1. зависит ли объем базы данных на скорость выполнения выборки/обновления/добавления строк из таблиц?
   Если да, то:
2. с каких объемов это начинает сильно ощущаться (к примеру если речь идет о 3 таблицах с 5-6млн записей это норм или уже слишком много??)
3. от чего еще зависит быстродействие базы данных?

Comment: От индексов, от транзакций, от алгоритмов, от носителя информации... много от чего

Comment: Не используйте `sqlite` для таких целей, эта бд не может переваривать большие объемы данных, лучше всего выберите `PostgreSQL`

Comment: Честно сказать изучаю программирование всего пару месяцев и немного сложно сразу это все переварить.. Для того чтобы база стала  PostegreSQL нужно восполтзоваться библиотекой psycopg2? И она сама будет создавать базу нужного типа?

Comment: Хм, тут пишут, что вообще-то должно быстрее чем PostreSQL работать https://www.sqlite.org/speed.html  Покажите ваш код, что ли. Возможно, проблема не во вставке, а в поиске данных для UPDATE после того, как база разбухает. Индексы в базе вообще есть?

Comment: @CrazyElf таблицы содержат по 7 колонок, первая из которых всегда TEXT PRIMARY KEY (если я все правильно понимаю, то первичный ключ всегда автоматически индексируется и смысла в повторной индексации нет).  Все SQL запросы с UPDATE-ом следующего типа: cursor.execute('UPDATE table1 SET column=? WHERE column_with_primary_key = ?', (value1, value2)). То есть обновляются только колонки не относящиеся к первичному ключу, а поиск (WHERE) идет только по колонке с первичным ключом.  Весь код скинуть тут проблемно, так как он около 800 строк и почти каждая 30 строка это SQL запрос на выборку/обновление.

Comment: @JohnyDoe Ключ - текстовое поле? Уууу. Большое небось? С текстом не специальные текстовые базы работают мягко говоря не очень. Если есть возможность, нужно привязываться к полю с уникальным идентификатором в виде int или там uid, а если такого нет и нужно именно текст, то я бы пробовал от этого текста хэш какой-нибудь генерить и делать ключом поле с этим хэшем. Из обычного текстового поля индексы не очень получаются. Хотя я может и отстал от жизни, но раньше было так.

Comment: @CrazyElf В первой таблице ключ это поле с IMEI или IMSI (в среднем от 14 до 16 символов). В двух других - абонентские номера (от 6 до 10 символов).  Это много? Если перевести их в INT ситуация изменится? И еще вопрос, по поводу транзакций - вся работа по анализу файлов EXCEL ведется в теле конструкции with sqlite.connect (path_to_db) as connect:  и в теле нет ни одного подтверждения транзакции connect.commit(), то есть все транзакции подтверждаются одной пачкой с закрытием базы данных (а их миллионы). Это  влияет на быстродействие? Или лучше подтверждать пачками по 10000/100000/1000000?

Comment: @JohnyDoe Ну, вам надо пробовать варианты с транзакциями пачками или не пачками, я так не скажу будет ли лучше, но попробовать стоит. А с ключом не знаю, это не очень длинные строки в принципе, надо читать матчасть, что там как со строками в качестве ключа. Главное чтобы не оказалось, что в этом случае полный поиск каждый раз делается.